# Python: convert date format YYYY-mm-dd to dd-MON-yyyy with abbreviated month

Tags: python

I have a date that is a string in this format:

```
'2021-01-16'
```

And need to convert it to a string in this format:

```
'16-JAN-2021'
```

I am able to get most of it like this:

```
x = datetime.strptime('2021-01-16', '%Y-%m-%d')
x.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

But the month is not fully capitalized:

```
'16-Jan-2021'
```

Comment: Have you looked at ```datetime```?

Comment: How about `.upper()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `upper()` to capitalize the output string:

```py
from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.strptime('2021-01-16', '%Y-%m-%d')

print(x.strftime('%d-%b-%Y').upper())
# 16-JAN-2021
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Simply use upper().

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2021-01-16', '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y').upper()
'16-JAN-2021'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x.strftime('%d-%b-%Y').upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

I read answers with `upper()` function, here is another way using `%^b`

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('2011-01-16', '%Y-%m-%d')
formatted_date = date.strftime('%d-%^b-%Y')
print(formatted_date)
```

Goodluck!